# How to check if a record exists in the SQL Server database C# winform?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

My windows form application is about Book Store. I would like to display PO numbers in a ComboBox which didn't have create a Good Received Note.

This is the structure of this two tables.

PO Table-

[image]

GRN table

[image]

How to change following code?

```
 public void fillPOcombo()
 {
        DynamicConnection con = new DynamicConnection();
        con.mysqlconnection();
        con.sqlquery("select PO_No from TBL_PO");
        con.dataread();

        while (con.datareader.Read())
        {
            cmbpono.Items.Add((int)con.datareader["PO_NO"]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show us a SQL query that will return what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say as follows :

Change

```
con.sqlquery("select PO_No from TBL_PO");
```

to

```
con.sqlquery("select PO_No from TBL_PO where PO_No not in (select PO_No from GRN)");
```

Comment: Thank You very much.This is the exact thing i have needed.

Comment: No worries! Oyaāva saādarayaena paiḷaigananavaā !

Comment: Also consider using `EXCEPT` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @mjwills Good one.